# Find Retry Count in Command Handler and Call External service before moving to ErrorQueue in NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus

I am using NServiceBus with Timeout retry mechanism. I would like to call a service to process message before moving to Error Queue.( in last retry)

Is there any way to know the handler is calling last retry sothat based on count I can call service to process?

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need to find out. Instead, can subscribe to an event with [Error Notifications](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/recoverability/subscribing-to-error-notifications) feature to react to a message that has failed all the retries and will be moved to the error queue.

> When a message fails all retries and is forwarded to the error queue.

Comment: thank you. I see we can get the retry count from the Message Headers. first time this wont available but next onwards we can see the Header Message with count.

Comment: And you know when the message is about to be moved to the error queue. Which I think is what you eluded to in your question. And if so, you could indicate the question is answered to help folks that search for this info to know the answer will help them as well. Cheers.